# Facebook User IP

Tags: facebook, networking

I am trying to write a facebook app that gets the users ip address,
with his knowledge of course, is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Is that all you needed to know, or do you also want to know how to do it?

Comment: :) should have asked how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, as your app on facebook is regular server side script (for example `PHP`), you could use `$_SERVER` var to access client IP. (if you meant PHP, check here http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php on `REMOTE_ADDR`)

Comment: the worry i have is that ill get facebook's server ip instead of the users

Comment: So stop worry, your app will be in `<iframe>` element, so it loaded by user's browser. :)